# @Column gets ignored in subclasses of my JPA-Entity

Tags: java, inheritance, spring-data-jpa

I created 2 JPA entities for my Spring Boot project: HopEntity (Superclass) and TruckEntity(Subclass of Hop).  Truck defines the String "regionGeoJson" and is supposed to be of type "text" in my database, due to some of my geojsons exceeding the limit of varchar(255).

Both are represented on the same table.

I used the `@Column` annotation with the field `columndefinition = "text"` to tell the table generator to make this column of type text, but for some reason it always generates it as varchar(255). After some trying around I found out that the `@Column` annotation seems to be completely ignored by the generator.

Below are my 2 classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_hops")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@SuperBuilder
public class HopEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    protected long id;

    //some fields
}
```

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@SuperBuilder
public class TruckEntity extends HopEntity {

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    @NotNull(message = "regionGeoJson may not be null")
    private String regionGeoJson;

    @Column
    @NotNull(message = "numberPlate may not be null")
    private String numberPlate;

}
```

this is my properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=${db-url}
spring.datasource.username=${db-username}
spring.datasource.password=${db-password}
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

Any Solution for this?

Edit / Additional Info:

Using the `@MappedSuperClass` annotation is not an option due to HopEntity being used as a foreign key.
The mentioned class is below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_warehouseNextHops")
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class WarehouseNextHopsEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column
    protected long id;

    @Column
    @NotNull(message = "traveltimeMins may not be null")
    @Min(value = 1, message = "traveltimeMins may not be lower than 1")
    private Integer traveltimeMins;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_next_hop")
    private HopEntity hop;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_warehouse")
    private WarehouseEntity warehouse;
}
```

Comment: you should prob change to create-drop on your properties file update does not change the table if its already generated only use update to production or if you need to test things with update

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want one table, you can put `@MappedSuperclass` above `HopEntity` and remove the `@Entity` annotation from it.

Alternatively, you can also put `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)` above your parent table.

I recommend looking more into JPA inheritance. [This](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance) is a pretty good article.

Comment: The MappedSuperclass annotation is not an option due to another Entity using an HopEntity as a foreign key. I'll add the mentioned class to the question in an edit.

Also the Inheritence seems redundant, due to the article you linked specifically mentioning that it is used by default if no strategy is specifically stated.